# Question related to Cyber Crime, where should it be asked?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question related to cyber crime that I want to ask on Stack Exchange.  Which would be an apt Stack Exchange network to discuss and ask.

Comment: What about cyber crime do you want to ask?  Can you provide an example question?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/I-am-informed-that-if-I-lodge-FIR-or-go-to-Supreme-Court-I-may-have-to-suffer-What-should-I-do?__snids__=328052165&__nsrc__=2

Comment: That looks to be offtopic across the entire network.  It's excessively subjective, very broad, not very clear, etc.

Comment: i think ther's a security site

Comment: To what thanks. His comment is very broad, not clear etc (mb hatred). As it gives no context. Just those words (which are very broad... etc).

Comment: Law.stackexchange is up, but it explicitly forbids questions asking for legal advice, like that one.